# NodePort not accessible on all nodes in a k3s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I've got a 3 node `k3s` cluster, installed using the following commands on fresh Ubuntu server 22.04 installs:

```
# first server
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s - server --cluster-init
# other two
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_TOKEN='$K3S_TOKEN' sh -s - server \
--server '$K3S_URL'
```

After creating a simple "hello world" pod and `NodePort` service, I noticed that I could only access the pod from the node that the pod was running on.  I also noticed that `kube-proxy` isn't running and I'm pretty sure it should be.

I checked the logs and found these two lines repeating but nothing else related to `kube-proxy`:

```
Feb 27 16:03:01 bigrig k3s[1621]: time="2024-02-27T16:03:01-05:00" level=info msg="Running kube-proxy --cluster-cidr=10.42.0.0/16 --conntrack-max-per-core=0 --conntrack-tcp-timeout-close-wait=0s --conntrack-tcp-timeout-established=0s --healthz-bind-address=127.0.0.1 --hostname-override=bigrig --kubeconfig=/var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/kubeproxy.kubeconfig --proxy-mode=iptables"
Feb 27 16:03:01 bigrig k3s[1621]: I0227 16:03:01.445209    1621 server.go:632] "kube-proxy running in dual-stack mode" primary ipFamily="IPv4"
```

I made sure that `conntrack` is installed per the [official debug docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-service/#is-kube-proxy-running) and restarted all my nodes but still no `kube-proxy` and still not able to access `NodePort` on nodes that the pod isn't running on.

I feel like I'm missing something.  I'm on fresh Ubuntu installations setting up a mostly default `k3s` deploy, not sure why such a core component is failing.  Help appreciated.